# ELMAH and Exception Management in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, elmah

I am looking at moving away from the Exception Management Application Block in the Enterprise Library for a new ASP.NET MVC site.

Scott Hansleman's post(s) on ELMAH has caught my eye but I don't fully understand the approach.  Typically I would suppress some exceptions (ones that are recoverable), log them in a central repository, and then display a message to the user as appropriate.

ELMAH seems focused on, "Logging of nearly all unhandled exceptions.". What about exceptions I want to handle? Can I use the same repository so there is one central location for all exceptions?

How are people using ELMAH in their applications, is it the only exception handling solution being implemented, or is it used in conjunction with another solution?

Answer (score 0):

Been a while since this was asked, but there are a few solutions out there for this:

1. [New Relic](http://newrelic.com) Mostly focused on application performance, but does unhandled exceptions.
2. [CodeAlert](http://codealertapp.com) Solely focused on exception handling and reporting - gives you the granularity you're looking for to do global vs. individual exceptions to a central repository.
3. [Preemptive](http://preemptive.com) Another application performance app, but with exception support.