# Logging all yellow screen of deaths, even when its a compilation problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, elmah

Earlier today we experienced a YSOD on one of our MVC sites running on IIS on Windows Server 2003.

Usually, these are reported via e-mail using ELMAH (using [this setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061389/elmah-and-exception-management-in-asp-net-mvc/1061502#1061502)), but since this was a compilation issue (of some sort), it did not get reported via e-mail.

The specific error was:

> "The directory 'App_GlobalResources'
>   is not allowed because the application
>   is precompiled."

This is a major problem, since a potential customer could notice the problem before we do. How can we make sure these YSODs are logged, when the exception handler on the site is not called?

Comment: Great question. If things die very early in an app it is hard to even try to log. Looking forward to what others have to say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to monitor the event log with VBScript.  You could then email this when it occurs:

Here's an example:

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/resources/qanda/feb07/hey0226.mspx
and email from vbscript:
http://www.paulsadowski.com/WSH/cdo.htm

You could do this with powershell and/or another .net app on the box also.

Comment: Thanks. I found this serverfault question helpful as well: http://serverfault.com/questions/47953/windows-event-log-email-notification

Answer (score 4):

If you can, check the event viewer on that machine.  This is the logger of last resort on a Windows machine.

Comment: The event viewer had it logged. Can we easily report these events via e-mail?

Comment: You can but I don't have any experience doing so.  You will need to write a custom solution or use a monitoring tool to accomplish this.  Perhaps the folks over at http://serverfault.com will be able to help you with this part.